# Can one create a control at runtime by specifying its class name as a string?

Tags: c++builder, rtti

Instead of,

```cpp
TButton *button = new TButton(MyForm);
```

Can one do something like this?

```cpp
TControl *control = new TControl(MyForm, "TButton");
```

Comment: If you make a hashmap, array, or something else where you keep a string name and what constructor function to call, probably

Comment: Youre better off with templates tho

Comment: I don't think I can use templates because the ClassName string is not known at compile time.

Comment: There are a finite number of controls, all other strings are invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Delphi, it is possible to create an object instance given a class' metatype from RTTI. After all, this is exactly what DFM streaming does at runtime.

But in C++, you cannot do anything like that with RTTI.

So, you will have to either:

1. Have your C++ code create its own lookup table of string-to-function mappings, where the functions call the appropriate class constructors, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

std::map<std::string, std::function<TControl*(TComponent*)>> mymap;
...
mymap["TButton"] = [](TComponent *Owner) -> TControl* { return new TButton(Owner); };
...
```

Or:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <map>

typedef TControl* (*CreateControlFunc)(TComponent*);
std::map<std::string, CreateControlFunc> mymap;
...
TControl* CreateButton(TComponent *Owner) { return new TButton(Owner); }
mymap["TButton"] = &CreateButton;
...
```

Either way, then you can do:

```cpp
TControl *control = mymap["TButton"](MyForm);
```

2. Write a Delphi function in a `.pas` unit to handle object creation by class name, and then add that file to your C++Builder project. When you compile the project, an `.hpp` file will be output that you can `#include` in your C++ code.

```pascal
unit CreateControlHelper;

interface

uses
  Classes, Controls;

function CreateControlByClassName(const ClassName: String; Owner: TComponent): TControl;

implementation

function CreateControlByClassName(const ClassName: String; Owner: TComponent): TControl;
var
  Cls: TPersistentClass;
begin
  Cls := FindClass(ClassName);
  if (Cls <> nil) and Cls.InheritsFrom(TControl) then
    Result := TControlClass(Cls).Create(Owner)
  else
    Result := nil;
end;

end.
```

```cpp
#include "CreateControlHelper.hpp"

TControl *control = CreateControlByClassName("TButton", MyForm);
```

**Update:**

3. *in theory*, you might also be able to use [Enhanced RTTI](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Working_with_RTTI), as its implementation is based in Delphi, eg:

```cpp
#include <System.Rtti.hpp>

TRttiMethod* FindControlConstructor(TRttiType *Type)
{
    while (Type)
    {
        DynamicArray<TRttiMethod*> methods = Type->GetDeclaredMethods();
        for(int i = 0; i < methods.Length; ++i)
        {
            TRttiMethod *method = methods[i];
            if ((method->Name == "Create") && (method->IsConstructor))
            {
                DynamicArray<TRttiParameter*> params = method->GetParameters();
                if ((params.Length == 1) && (params[0]->ParamType->Handle == __typeinfo(TComponent)))
                {
                    return method;
                }
            }
        }
        Type = Type->BaseType;
    }
    return NULL;
}

TControl* CreateControlByClassName(const String &QualifiedClassName, TComponent *Owner)
{
    TRttiContext ctx = TRttiContext::Create();
    TRttiType *type = ctx.FindType(QualifiedClassName);
    TRttiMethod *method = FindControlConstructor(type);
    if (method)
    {
        TValue val;
        val = Owner;
        TValue res = method->Invoke(type->AsInstance()->MetaclassType, &val, 0);
        return static_cast<TControl*>(res.AsObject());
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

```cpp
TControl *control = CreateControlByClassName("Vcl.StdCtrls.TButton", MyForm);
```

Comment: Nice! I was playing around with the C++ `TRttiMethod` to try to `Invoke` the `Create` method :-) ... but it's a dead end then I guess?

Comment: Ouch... I'm getting 7 `Create` mehods taking 1 parameter and 1 method taking 0 parameters for `TButton`. I've never done reflection stuff in C++ ... It feels a bit odd :)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm not sure, I've never tried that in C++.  In theory, it *may* work (see at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846824/, though). I have updated my answer with  an example.

Comment: That was fast :) Does `GetType` work with `String`? I tried `FindType` but it fails for `TButton`. I was however able to use `GetTypes()` to iterate over them to find `TButton`.

`auto creates = type->GetMethods("Create");` returns 8 methods in total. Perhaps it's the base classes `Create` methods too?

Edit: I think I might be iterating over them erroneously. Range based loop.

Comment: @TedLyngmo you are right, I meant `FindType()` not `GetType()`. I fixed that. As for the `"Create"`s, yeah it is possible that you might be seeing inherited constructors. A range-for loop works fine with `DynamicArray`. Try using `GetDeclaredMethods()` instead, which ignores inherited methods. I updated my example.

Comment: It's neat how you can mix Pascal with C++, but I'm getting an access violation with `TControl *control = CreateControlByClassName("TButton", MyForm);`, although the line `TButton *button = new TButton(MyForm);` in the same spot works as expected.  The `.hpp` file was created as expected, and included.  So I'm not sure why that would happen.  Thanks for the very thorough answer and I will be exploring the other options you listed.  Giving you best answer in the meantime.

Comment: @GirkovArpa make sure `FindClass(ClassName)` is not returning `nil`.  You may need to manually `RegisterClass()` the classes you are interested in.

Comment: I'm getting 0 length arrays with both `FindType()` and  `GetDeclaredMethods()`. For `FindType` I can work around it. I tried `GetDeclaredMethods` on `TCustomButton` instead and then I got 2 methods - One `Create` and one `Destroy`.

Comment: Nice again! I wonder if my strange results with `FindType` etc may be because I just added this to an existing test project fot FMX.

Comment: @TedLyngmo the fact that you are using FMX would have been nice to know. That means the last example will have to be changed to `CreateControlByClassName("FMX.StdCtrls.TButton", MyForm);`

Comment: I didn't know what OP used so I just took random test project. I tried the full FMX.StdCtrls.TButton too but got no type with FindType.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213723/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-ted-lyngmo).